# What does it mean to run a .ltb file through LaTeX?

Tags: bibliographies, texshop, amsrefs

The AMSRefs [package documentation](https://ctan.um.ac.ir/macros/latex/contrib/amsrefs/amsrdoc.pdf) says the following in Section 2.2 *Using an* `.ltb` *database file*:

> [S]uppose you have a file `nonsense.ltb` with the following contents:
>
> ```
> \documentclass{article}
>
> \usepackage{amsrefs}
>
> \begin{document}
>
> \begin{bibdiv}
>
> \begin{biblist}
>
> \bib{Bourbaki70}{book}{
>     title={Th\’eorie des ensembles},
>     author={Bourbaki, Nicolas},
>     date={1970},
>     publisher={Hermann},
>     address={Paris}
> }
>
> \bib{Sokal96}{article}{
>     title={Trangressing the boundaries},
>     subtitle={Toward a transformative hermeneutics of quantum gravity},
>     author={Sokal, Alan},
>     journal={Social Text},
>     volume={46/47},
>     date={1996},
>     pages={217--252}
> }
>
> \bib{SokalB1998}{book}{
>     title={Fashionable Nonsense},
>     subtitle={Postmodern Intellectuals’ Abuse of Science},
>     author={Sokal, Alan},
>     author={Bricmont, Jean},
>     publisher={Picador USA},
>     address={New York},
>     date={1998}
> }
>
> \end{biblist}
>
> \end{bibdiv}
>
> \end{document}
> ```
>
> Before seeing how this affects our sample document, take note of a couple of aspects of the format of `nonsense.ltb`:
>
> 1. We have chosen to format `nonsense.ltb` as a complete LaTeX document. This is so we can produce a formatted listing of our whole database by running `nonsense.ltb` through LaTeX. However, this is not necessary; when `amsrefs` treats `nonsense.ltb` as a database file, it ignores everything except for the `\bib` commands.
>
>    …

What is meant by "running `nonsense.ltb` through LaTeX"? Do I open the database file `nonsense.ltb` in my LaTeX editor (I am using TeXShop) and then run `pdftex`? But won't this require it to be a `.tex` file, rather than an `.ltb` file?

I actually tried creating a file `nonsense.ltb` with the above content and opening it in TeXShop, but the options to typeset the document as either 'Plain TeX' or 'LaTeX', etc. under the *Typeset* menu bar item are grayed out, and I'm unable to typeset the `.ltb` file. These are the options I see when I open in the menu bar in this case:

> [image]

This is how the menu bar item looks for other (`.tex`) documents that I am able to typeset using ⌘T.

> [image]

Comment: @TheAmplitwist You could always run it via command line. On the other hand, I do not see why you could not rename it as .tex-file. I fathom that the developers only use a different file extension to separate the document file from the bibliography-file, but if your LaTeX editor is too stubborn for that, just rename it into "*.tex". It is a full TeX-file after all, and will compile as long as `\usepackage{amsrefs}` defines the `bibdiv` and `biblist` environments.

Comment: The problem I see is that this will generate a separate .pdf-file with just the bibliography. I could imagine that the thinking behind the `amsrefs`-package is, that you are supposed to call the .ltb-file of the same name from within the .tex-file (although it would then be weird to structure the .ltb-file as a complete .tex-file with its own `documentclass{}` and `begin{document}`). The documentation of `amsrefs` should give you details on how it is supposed to be combined with the .tex-file to generate a bibliography integrated into the main document.

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf Thank you for your comments! Unfortunately, I am not (yet) familiar with the command line tools, so I do not know how to run the `.ltb` file through LaTeX via the command line. I tried your next suggestion and renamed the file as `nonsense.ltb.tex`, and also as `nonsense.tex`.  In both cases, TeXShop understands to compile it via LaTeX. Moreover, I am able to use `\bibselect{nonsense}` in my sample document successfully regardless of how the database file is named: `nonsense.ltb`, `nonsense.ltb.tex` and `nonsense.tex` all work fine. (My apologies in case all this is trivial.)

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf Perhaps the idea behind this is indeed as you suggest, namely to run the database file through LaTeX in order to generate a separate `.pdf` file with all the bibliography entries typeset…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeXShop is trying to be (not) very smart and it only allows files with extensions `.tex` and, as far as I can see, also `.ltx` to be typeset.

However, you can act on a hidden preference. On a Terminal window, type

```bash
defaults write TeXShop OtherTeXExtensions \(ltb\)
```

and hit return. Thereafter you will be able to typeset also `.ltb` files.

[image: Screenshot of the TeXShop editor with the file nonsense.ltb opened. The "Typeset" option is seen to be available.]

As you see, the “Typeset” button is no longer grayed out. Here's the console output:

[image: Screenshot of the console log after running LaTeX.]

The resulting PDF is:

[image: Screenshot of the typeset PDF.]

Alas, the hidden preference is not even listed in the documentation coming with the program.

The value of the preference must be a comma separated list in parentheses, so you could do

```bash
defaults write TeXShop OtherTeXExtensions \(ltb,abc,def\)
```

if you need to add other extensions.

Comment: Thank you! I tried changing the defaults as you instructed and it has worked. I have a couple of questions: (1) My curiosity, how did you locate this hidden preference that is not listed even in the documentation? :) (2) Can something "bad" happen if I try to typeset non `.tex` files (that is, other than the file not compiling at all)? Basically, I'm just wondering about why TeXShop's defaults are set the way they are.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist I tried to run `defaults read TeXShop` and the line with `OtherTeXExtensions=()` showed up. It was just a look at the other preferences to understand what writing in the preference. You can typeset *any* file with an extension from the Terminal, just run `pdflatex filename.ext`. If it is a well formed LaTeX file, you'll get the output. Apparently the author of TeXShop wanted to avoid running TeX on strange files. It is conceivable to craft a malicious file that hides `\write` instructions, but the usual settings of TeX Live prohibits writing in directories above the working one.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was instructive. :)